# Generating a Microsoft Word file in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I am able to generate a Microsoft word file, but I want the data in table structure. I have used an HTML table tag in PHP, but the output does not look satisfactory. In the table are a lot of cellspacing and cellpadding even if I have initialize them to zero space. Any idea how can I solve this?

here goes my code

```
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");
    $now_date = date('d-m-Y H:i');
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<div>Seminarthema:</div>\n";
    echo "<div>Termin:$now_date</div>";
    echo "<br></br>";
    echo "<div style='size:20px;'><h2>Teilnehmerliste</h2></div>";
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Buchungskreis</th><th>Kurs-ID</th><th>Teilgenommen</th></tr>";     
    $students = $GLOBALS["TYPO3_DB"]->exec_SELECTquery('*','tx_training_Registration','hidden=0 AND deleted=0');
    $countstud = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_num_rows($students); 
    if($countstud){ 
        while($row2 = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($students)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".utf8_decode($row2['firstname'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".utf8_decode($row2['lastname'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".utf8_decode($row2['companycode'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".utf8_decode($row2['trainingid'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".utf8_decode($row2[' status'])."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }   
    }                                 
    echo  "</table>";   
    echo "</head>";
    echo "</html>";
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the file? With *space* do you mean memory or space on the screen? Maybe CSV would be better. (I assume you are just generating a file containing words ;))

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on your question by explaining what you want to do, using full words (O/p = ?), complete sentences and proper terminology (are we to assume that "Word" is in fact Microsoft Word?)

Comment: @Felix Ya even i was in mood of doing it as csv...But my client want it in doc format..It has some Company logos And few more fancy things

Comment: @siddesh savant: Ah so it is indeed Microsoft Word. Please rephrase your question accordingly. Describe what you mean with space etc.

Comment: Well, you could start by telling us _how_ you are generating the MS Word file.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a Microsoft Word file though, more like a HTML file with .doc extension...

Comment: @Pekka: Unless the OP tells us, it could very well be an elephant carrying a wooden board with the table and a ".doc" tag tied on its tail. I, for one, am getting tired of guessing...

Comment: @thkala: Let's find that elephant :)

Comment: <blinks stupidly> What do you know... it _is_ an HTML document with a ".doc" extension and an MS Word mimetype. I didn't even know that Word could open something like this without choking. I highly doubt that's what your clients want. No matter the extension, it's still an HTML document.

Comment: This is not a MS word form of either BIFF or Office Open XML format, it's simply a text file containing HTML markup with a .doc extension and ms work doc format headers... yet another person who believes that PHP automagically converts files for them

Comment: Maybe try resetting `padding` and `margin` properties on each cell individually. But it could be that Word simply adds spacing of its own

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not consider creating a "real" Word document rather than a "make-believe that HTML is actually Word" file. Take a look at [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/).

Comment: thanks a lot..I was allconfused...

Comment: I gone through the manual....I am using Ubuntu system...Will that open in it

Comment: Ubuntu is just an operating system. You need an application to open Word documents: that could be Microsoft Word itself (on Windows PCs or under WINE on Ubuntu) or Open Office Writer. How are you opening your "fake" Word documents now?

Comment: sorry for late relpy....I am opening using openoffice

Comment: Well Open Office Writer (certainly the version 3.2 that I'm running) is quite capable of Opening Word documents (whether .doc or .docx)